# How many different combinations of a six sided die rolls equals n

Tags: discrete-mathematics, combinations

Say I want to roll a six-sided-die until all the rolls I have made added together equal X (for example a number like 812). How do I calculate how many different possible combinations of dice rolls add up to X?

for example:
say I want to find the different roll combinations that equal 6:
6
51
15
42
24
33
123
312
213
114
411
141
1113
3111
1311
1131
11112
21111
12111
11211
11121
and so on...

I have found that this approach does not work for larger numbers. Thanks

Thanks

Comment: You missed out a lot of combinations in your example, such as $1,1,1,1,1,1$

Comment: A somewhat brute-force approach is to use generating functions.  Letting $[x^n]$ denote the operation of returning the coefficient of $x^n$ from the expansion of whatever follows (*e.g. $[x^3](5x^3+3x^2+x+1)=5$*) we have the total will be $\sum\limits_{k=0}^n [x^n]((x+x^2+\dots+x^6)^k)$.  Of course, this isn't particularly useful for hand-calculations but its fine for a computer.

Comment: Thanks you, I have updated it

Comment: In essence, what you are asking for is the number of [compositions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(combinatorics)) of your desired number, but with the restriction that partsizes be between 1 and 6 as in [restricted partitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)#Restricted_partitions), like a restricted ordered partition if you will.

Comment: @JMoravitz Thank you! I want to write an algorithm to do this calculation, and this will help a lot

Comment: @halibet1234 don't bother with that approach, it will be incredibly time consuming for large $n$.  The recurrence relation I detail below will be a much more efficient approach to implement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of the clunky generating function approach I mentioned in the comments above, a stronger tool to use for this specific problem is recurrence relations.

Let $a_n$ represent the number of [compositions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(combinatorics)) of the number $n$ **using only the numbers** $1,2,\dots,6$

As the upper bound condition doesn't come into play for $n\leq 6$ these numbers **when $n\leq 6$ (not when $n>6$)** are the same as the number of ordinary compositions, i.e. $a_1=1, a_2=2, a_3=4, a_4=8, a_5=16, a_6=32$

For $n\geq 7$ any partition of $n$ into parts none of which exceeding $6$ will either end with a $1$, end with a $2$, ..., or end with a $6$.  There are exactly $a_{n-1},a_{n-2},\dots,a_{n-6}$ of each of these such compositions respectively.

We have then the recurrence relation

$$a_n = a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}+\dots+a_{n-6}$$

Similar to the fibonacci numbers, these are what some people call the [Hexanacci Numbers](http://oeis.org/A001592)

$\begin{array}{rl}a_1&=1\\ a_2&=2\\a_3&=4\\a_4&=8\\a_5&=16\\a_6&=32\\\hline\end{array}$

$\begin{array}{lrl}a_7&=a_6+a_5+a_4+a_3+a_2+a_1&=32+16+8+4+2+1&=63\\a_8&=a_7+a_6+a_5+a_4+a_3+a_2&=63+32+16+8+4+2&=125\\a_9&=a_8+a_7+a_6+a_5+a_4+a_3&=125+63+32+16+8+4&=248\\ \vdots\\
a_n&=a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}+a_{n-3}+a_{n-4}+a_{n-5}+a_{n-6}\end{array}$

Comment: So if I understand correctly for say

Comment: @halibet1234 That comment does not make any sense to me.  It seems you began a thought and never completed it.  It would be like if

Comment: Sorry I hit enter for a new line and it submitted it lol. So if I understand correctly for say a10=a10−6+a10−5+a10−4+a10−3+a10−2+a10−1 will equal 2^4 + 2^5 + 2^6 + 2^7 + 2^8 + 2^9 = 1008?

Comment: No, not quite because $a_{10-1}=a_9$ is not equal to $2^9$ (*and not equal to $2^{9-1}$ either which is the pattern you should have thought*).  The pattern that $a_n=2^{n-1}$ breaks at $a_7$ which is equal to $63$ not $64$.  You have $a_7=a_1+a_2+a_3+a_4+a_5+a_6=63\neq 64$, then $a_8=a_2+a_3+a_4+a_5+a_6+a_7=2+4+8+16+32+63=125\neq 128$.

Comment: The formula on the wikipedia is An = 2^n-1. Do I need to subtract an additional 1 when calculating? For example, a_10-6 = 2^4-1?

Comment: The formula $2^{n-1}$ it gives is for compositions with no restriction on part size, i.e. it allows for parts of size $7, 8,9,\dots$ as well, allowing for example for $10$ the compositions $10,9+1,1+9,2+8,1+1+8,1+8+1,\dots$ which you did not allow since you said you are rolling six-sided dice, not infinite-sided dice.  The formula for *your* question, I gave above as a recurrence relation.  A nice clean closed form doesn't look like it exists.  (*it would require factoring the polynomial $x^6-x^5-x^4-x^3-x^2-x-1$...*)

Comment: ohhhh okay, I think I see how to calculate it now. a_7=2^0+2^1+2^2+2^3+2^4+2^5=63. Then for a_8 I can calculate a_2 through a_ as 2^n-1, but for a_7 as so forth I have to use the formula. So for a_100 I would have to recursively calculate up to a_99.

Comment: That would be the easy way to do it, yes.  It should just run in $O(n)$ time and use only a small amount of memory (*you can keep track of only the most recent six entries in the sequence and overwrite the earlier terms once they are no longer needed*), unlike the generating function approach I mentioned originally in the comments, which with an efficient approach would still run in at least $O(n^2)$ time and use up a huge amount of memory.

Comment: Thank you so much! I will start working on an algorithm to calculate this

Comment: I dont think this takes into consideration the duplicates, say for example f 1+5 and 5+1 are not catered for, these are duplicates. Any ideas on how to cater for those?

Comment: @user3 correct, that is a different problem entirely.  For that use stars and bars with inclusion-exclusion or partition numbers, whichever meets your specific problem.  Ask a new question for more details instead of asking in comments of an old question like this and be sure to clarify what does or doesn't count as different arrangements.

Comment: I am not a maths major! Just trying to gulp these concepts one at a time!

Comment: However something similar exists here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1895119/how-many-ways-to-reach-nth-number-from-starting-point-using-any-number-steps-b

Comment: Again, the problem you are referring to is somewhat off topic here.  The OP was clearly interested in the case where 1+5 and 5+1 are considered different so that was the question that I originally answered.  Again, if you have a different question then continue searching or ask a new question.

Comment: Thanks, I added a new one [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2544575/how-to-exclude-similar-pairs-from-a-series)

Comment: @user3 the question you linked to in your earlier comment is a duplicate of this one and treats 1+5 as different than 5+1.

Comment: Yes but I am not able to understand that problem properly, There is no specific formula which I can implement in code! Like the one you provided. Sorry if I am sounding a bit dumb here.