# A better way to prove $|x - w| + |y - z| \geq |x - z| + |y - w|$ if $x\leq y$ and $z\leq w$

Tags: inequality, alternative-proof

Let $x\leq y$ and $z\leq w$. Prove that:

$|x - w| + |y - z| \geq |x - z| + |y - w|$

This can be proved by taking cases for $y$ and using the triangle inequality:

for $y \geq w$ :

$|x - w| + |y - z| \geq |x - z| + |y - w|$

$|x - w| + (y - z) \geq |x - z| + (y - w)$

$(w - z) + |y - z| \geq |y - w|$

$|w - z| + |y - z| \geq |y - w|$ (true from the triangle inequality)

Then work similarly for the cases $z \leq y < w$ and $y < z$

I'm wondering if there is a way to prove that which doesn't involve as many cases and operations.

Comment: Why $|x-w|=x-w$?

Comment: @BobDobbs sorry, my mistake, where it reads "Let $x \leq y$ and $z \leq w$" it should read instead "Let $x \geq y$ and $z \geq w$". I've amended it. Due to symmetry, this amendment is still the same theorem :)

Comment: @MartinR yes, you are right, I've amended it again to the original inequality and rewrote the proof instead to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without loss of generality and assuming $w\geq z$ and $y\geq x$, we may assume that one of $y$ and $w$ is the leftist (most left) point on the real line. Say $w$ is the leftist point. Then,

$|x - w| + |y - z| \geq |x - z| + |y - w|\iff x - w + |y - z| \geq |x - z| +y - w\iff$

$x-y + |y - z| \geq |x-z|\iff |x-y| + |y - z| \geq |x-z|$

which is true by triangular inequality.

Comment: Yeap, I think this is as simple as it can get, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

We assume here that $x\le y$ and $z\le w$.

The function $f(t) = |t-w| - |t-z|$ is continuous and it is differentiable except at points $w$ and $z$ with
\begin{equation}
f'(t) = \text{sgn}(t-w)-\text{sgn}(t-z) \le 0
\end{equation}
because $\text{sgn}()$ is non-decreasing and $t-w\le t-z$.

It follows that $f$ is non-increasing in $\mathbb{R}$, hence $f(x)\ge f(y)$, i.e.
\begin{equation}
|x-w|-|x-z|\ge |y-w|-|y-z|\tag*{$\blacksquare$}
\end{equation}

Comment: This is a nice proof!

Comment: @MartinR The proof also works for $\varphi(t-w)-\varphi(t-z)$ if $\varphi$ is a differentiable convex function. One could argue that every convex function is a limit of differentiable convex functions to get the result for every convex function.

Comment: Yes, I had noticed that, and there are various ways to obtain that $\varphi(t-w)-\varphi(t-z)$ is non-decreasing for a convex function $\varphi$. One (among others) is that $\varphi(t) = \int_0^t \varphi'(s) ds$ where $\varphi'$ is the left or right derivative (which exists everywhere and is non-decreasing).

Comment: (Of course $t \mapsto \varphi(t-w)-\varphi(t-z)$  increasing is *equivalent* to $ \varphi(x - w) + \varphi(y - z) \geq \varphi(x - z) + \varphi(y - w)$ which can be proven directly from the convexity condition.)

Answer (score 2):

Slightly more general one can show that if $x\leq y$ and $z\leq w$ then
$$
f(x - w) + f(y - z) \geq f(x - z) + f(y - w)
$$
for any *convex* function $f: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$. Your inequality is a special case because $f(t) = |t|$ is convex.

For a proof let
$$
 a = x-w, b= x-z, c = y-w, d= y-z \, .
$$
Then
$$
 a \le b \le d \, , \\
 a \le c \le d \, 
$$
and
$$
 a+d = b+c \, .
$$
If $a=d$ then $a=b=c=d$ and we are done. Otherwise
$$
 f(b) \le \frac{d-b}{d-a}f(a) + \frac{b-a}{d-a}f(d) \\
 f(c) \le \frac{d-c}{d-a}f(a) + \frac{c-a}{d-a}f(d) \\
$$
and adding these inequalities gives
$$
 f(b) + f(c) \le f(a) + f(d) \, .
$$

This is also a special case of [Karamata's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karamata%27s_inequality) with
$$
\begin{align}
 (x_1, x_2) &= (d, a) \, ,\\
 (y_1, y_2) &= (\max(b,c), \min(b, c) \, .
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Are you reading Hindu books? What is Karamata's inequality? Come on. It is better to check cases.

Comment: @BobDobbs: Karamata's inequality is a generalization of Jensen's inequality for convex functions, see the given link.